# JPA creating a trimmed down entity version of an existing Entity

Tags: java, hibernate, angularjs, jpa, orm

I have a Angular Client and a REST backend through Spring REST/MVC. The database is MySQL and I'm using JPA with Hibernate for ORM.

Some of my front end views require me to de-normalize some domain-data on the Java side. 
I have a typical User Domain object with id,fname,lname etc.. This User object points to 'user' table in the database. Nothing unusual.

The problem is that I have another object "simplecost" that has the following structure

```
public class SimpleCost {
 private Long id;
 private Long userId;
 private Long cost;
}
```

A collection of above objects is utilized by the frontend to generate a view like this

```
userId  cost
1        5.5
2        7.5
3        10.00
```

But what the view is supposed to be is

```
Name                cost
John Doe            5.5
Jane Doe            7.5
Rusty Shackleford   10.00
```

So instead of sending just the userId with the SimpleCost object, I also need to send the fname and lname.

To solve this problem I tried (failing miserably) the following approach.
I created a new domain object called "UserBare". This is a trimmed down version of the "User". What I mean by this is that "UserBare" only has an fname and lname.

I added "UserBare" as a new member of SimpleCost object

New proposed structure of SimpleCost

```
public class SimpleCost {
 private Long id;
 private Long userId;
 private Long cost;
 private UserBare user;
}
```

But I'm unable to populate the user object using JPA. I tried OnetoOne join which didn't work. I also tried adding String fname, String lname fields to SimpleCost instead and then a @SecondaryTable annotation to populate those values with @Column(table="user", name="fName"). This didn't work as well.

Here is my database structure

User

```
CREATE TABLE `user` (
`id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`fName` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
`lName` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
`mName` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
`title` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
`email` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `id_UNIQUE` (`id`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=9 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
 /*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
```

simplecost

```
CREATE TABLE `simplecost` (
`id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`userId` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
`liableCost` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
`isActive` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
UNIQUE KEY `id_UNIQUE` (`id`),
KEY `fk_simplecost_user1_idx` (`userId`),
CONSTRAINT `fk_simplecost_user` FOREIGN KEY (`userId`) REFERENCES `user`      (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=13 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want the join to work you have to do this:

```
public class SimpleCost {
 private Long id;
 private User user;
 private Long cost;
}

public class User{
    private Long id;
    private String fName;
    private String lName;
    priavte String mName;
    priavate String title;
    private String email;
}
```

also if i were you i would rename the columns `"id"` to `"userId"` and `"simpleCostId"`